# How to override reloadRowsAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to override a the method `reloadRowAtIndexPath` for tableView cell.

I wanna do same as when you override `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        if(isUserTalking(indexPath))
        {
            return userMessageCell(indexPath)
        }
        else
        {
            if(isNotUserFirstMessage(indexPath))
            {
                return notUserFirstMessageCell(indexPath)
            }
            else
            {
                return notUserNotFirstMessageCell(indexPath)
            }
        }

    }
```

In that way :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, reloadRowsAtIndexPaths indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        print("job")
            if(isNotUserFirstMessage(indexPath))
            {
                return notUserFirstMessageCell(indexPath, showImage: false)
            }
            else
            {
                return notUserNotFirstMessageCell(indexPath, showImage: false)
            }
    }
```

but when I use `self.myTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPath` it never calls the override version.

Do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` isn't really meant for this. You probably want to use 
`tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)` instead. E.g.:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("job")
    if isNotUserFirstMessage(indexPath) {
        configureNotUserFirstMessageCell(cell, showImage: false)
    } else {
        configureNotUserNotFirstMessageCell(cell, showImage: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I'll try it now, but how we can call this method on a specific row ?

Comment: Just add it to your table view delegate and it will get called automatically when a cell is shown.

Comment: Here, when there is an insert I want to check the previous inserted cell and then show its image or not. You think it will work ?

Comment: @Bram'in Only one way to find out! Try it :)

Comment: I'm trying but there is an error about the return in a void function :( 
If I had a return type it says that's function is non conform to protocol :(

Comment: @Bram'in oops, my mistake--just corrected. You'll need to implement two new functions to configure the cells for each state. Let me know if the above isn't clear.